# Not able to access Excel File on IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed an asp.net application. In that application I created the Interop Object with the help of which I am opening an Excel file.This thing works fine at the Local system. But when I try to open the application from the Localhost IIS Server it is showing me the error that Microsoft Excel cannot access the file.I have used the following code.

```
            addBatch.WA = new Excel.Application();

            addBatch.workbookPath = @"D:\Barcode_Details.xlsx";
            addBatch.excelWorkbook = WA.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            addBatch.excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You don't have rights to access files on your computer, except them in your virtual dir!
So, you need to put the excell file in your project directory, for example in App_Data and then change the path as follows

```
   addBatch.workbookPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Barcode_Details.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code in try catch block, and try extract the error message

if the error is Dynamic operations cannot be performed on the homogenous AppDomain then go to the Web.config file of port no 80 try to change trust legacyCasModel=false level="Full"

if the error is Access Denied of Com Exception 
win+r->dcomcnfg->componentservices-> computer->dcom config ->microsoft Excel Application-> rightclick to get properties

In general tab change authentication type to None.

I hope it solves! i faced the same issue